# .htaccess changes blocked by cache?

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache

I read everywhere that .htaccess isn't stored in the browser's cache. But I made changes (RewriteRule) which don't work in Chrome (my standard browser) but when I use inkognito-mode or a different browser it works fine. How is that possible and how can change it, that people will see the changes? My code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.aaa.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.bbb.com/cms/index.php/abc [R=301,L]
```

thanks!

Comment: The simplest solution is change R=301 to R, if you dont want it to be cached. 301 is a permanent redirect ,browsers may cache it, R is Temp redirect it is not cached .

Comment: That's what I found out myself but it does not work for me? /: